# Network debugging specific to network carriage

Tags: ios, debugging, networking, afnetworking, server

I have an iPhone application in which I have a request which works fine on wifi and with all network carriages but one carriage. On this carriage, if I use ASIHttpRequest, it gives me the below error:

```
ASIHTTPRequest request_didFail: Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo=0xd54e2f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0xd502de0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)", NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred}
```

If I use AFNetworking it returns below error:

```
NSLocalizedDescription = "Could not connect to the server.";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 \"Could not connect to the server.\" UserInfo=0xdc98630 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://sitename.com, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://sitename.com, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}";
```

First of all, what could be the reason of this error assuming it only happens for a specific carrier? Second, as the request works with everything but this carriage, it seems hard to debug, so how can I debug it to find the exact problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was with this specific telco. Without changing the code, it started to work again after some time. 
For the answer to this question, I can say that the reason could be about some proxy thing that is made by the telco and we tried to debug it by applying different proxy tests.